# Creating a button in PowerPoint VBA, but it's not clickable

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working in Excel VBA, creating a PowerPoint presentation.
I am trying to place <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> buttons on each slide.  I am using the code below:

```
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application, ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation, ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shpNextButton As PowerPoint.Shape
Set ppApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\test1.pptm")
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(ppPres.slides.count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
Set shpNextButton = ppSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeActionButtonForwardorNext, 750, 480, 40, 12.5)
With shpNextButton.TextFrame.TextRange
     .Text = "Next"
     With .Font
          .Size = 10
          .name = "Arial"
     End With
End With
shpNextButton.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionNextSlide
```

This code creates the button with the correct text on it.  However in the PowerPoint slide, the button is clickable.  When I click on it, it just acts like a regular shape.

Comment: Perhaps you you forgot to `PowerPoint.ppLayoutBlank` (=12),  `PowerPoint.ppMouseClick` (=1) and `PowerPoint.ppActionNextSlide` (=1)? But i recommend to use late binding and replace PowerPoint specific constants with it's value to prevent issues when it's at a different computer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I do have the layout action settings and action in my code.  i just can't figure out why the button isn't clickable.

Comment: Are you in slide show view when you click the buttons your code has added?  Action settings/hyperlinks etc. only work in slide show view, not Normal or other views.

Comment: okay, see all that stuff on my face.  That's egg.  Thanks for the reminder Steve Rindsberg.  And thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me when I use an adapted version of it (removing lines 1,3,4 and setting a reference to the current slide for line 5) within the PowerPoint VBE so the only thing I can think of is that the 'pp' constants are not set if you haven't added the PowerPoint library to your project. What do you get in the Immediate window if you type this?

```
?ppActionNextSlide
```

It should return 1 if all is ok. If it returns 0 then that's equivalent to **ppActionNone** which would explain what's happening.

By the way, your code added the button outside of my 4:3 slide so I assume you're using a 16:9 slide layout. It would be better to reference the right hand side of the side less an offset to avoid this potential issue with:

```
ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
```

Comment: JamieG - you're saying that you actually got a button that you could click and go to the next slide?  I don't have a problem creating the button.  But when I click on it, nothing happens.  it is basically treating it like a regular shape.  When I type ?ppActionNextSlide in the Immediate window, I get a return value of 1.